# htaccess rewrite rule for subfolder (nice url)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have trying to figure out how to get working in subfolder "admin" the same thing which works in root dir, problem is I don't know how to do that.

Currently I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?arg=$1 [L,QSA]

# /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[[:alnum:]]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301]
```

Now it works like: 
http://example.com/page translate into http://example.com/?arg=page

What I would like to do in addition is this:
http://example.com/admin/page translate into http://example.com/admin/?arg=page

I don't know at all how to make that happen, can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: you can save yourself a lot of hassle by using a routing-lib like [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) or [klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these rules with appropriate `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?arg=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I created .htaccess with your data in admin folder, results in http://example.com/admin//////////////////////

Comment: Try my updated answer after clearing your browser cache

Answer (score 3):

Or just add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php?arg=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Whats not working? This is the correct rule. Do you have index.php in admin/index.php? Put var_dump($_GET['arg']) there, you should see it

Comment: Problem is that I use same thing on root folder, so I get redirection to root folder from admin, it using arg=/admin/page instead example.com/admin/?arg=page

Comment: My new rule will not work on root folder, only on admin folder. Put this rule first and then your other rule. Or better just have everything routed to a main file, say app.php, and handle routing from there accordingly.

Comment: I get correct solution from anubhava, anyway thanks for help!