# How to use .htaccess RewriteRule with index in the root directory, but the URI listing sub-directories?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am having issues getting my site to rewrite sub-directory locations back to my public/index.php.

Here is my file structure (simple version):

```
public -> index.html and .htaccess

private -> views -> my viewable .php files
      -> src -> router.php (does the routing
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<body>
    <?php
    router();
    ?>
</body>
```

router.php

```
function router()
{
    $request = trim(strtolower(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
    
    $fileName = PRIVATE_PATH . "/views/" . $request . ".php";
    if ($request == "/") { // * WHERE TO GO FOR THE 'HOME' PAGE * //
        require_once(PRIVATE_PATH . "/views/home.php"); // ? CAN CHANGE THIS FROM 'home.php' TO OTHER FILE NAME AS DESIRED ? //
    } elseif (file_exists($fileName)) { // * LINKS WILL HAVE THE SAME LOCATION AS THE FILENAME (SANS THE .PHP) * //
        require_once($fileName);
    } else { // * CATCH ALL FOR PAGE NOT FOUND - 404 ERROR * //
        http_response_code(404);
        require_once(PRIVATE_PATH . "/views/404.php");
    }
}
```

I've read numerous SO pages:
[Redirect all to index.php using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess)
[RewriteRule in sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731303/rewriterule-in-sub-folder)
[.htaccess URL Rewrite to Subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864507/htaccess-url-rewrite-to-subdirectory)
[htaccess rewrite rule for subfolder (nice url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757707/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-subfolder-nice-url)

I'd prefer not to have it rewrite (visably) as a $_GET `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

I am using https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/ as my base to do this - I added one of the comment's suggestions --

```
function getBaseURI()
{
    $basePath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
    // Get the current Request URI and remove rewrite base path from it
    // (= allows one to run the router in a sub folder)
    $uri = substr(rawurldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), strlen($basePath));
    // Don't take query params into account on the URL
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) {
        $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    }
    // Remove trailing slash + enforce a slash at the start
    return '/' . trim($uri, '/');
}

$request = getBaseURI();
```

It would pull the proper file; however, my index.php file's  links such as `<script src='./assets/jquery363.min.js'></script>` started trying to pull from the sub-directories...

e.g.: If I put localhost/zero/one/two it would pull from views/zero/one/two.php but I would get a console error for unable to find jquery at localhost/zero/one/assets/jquery363.min.js.

Getting the information to pull from views (with sub-directories) is the easy part. I'm having trouble with my index file's linkages IF a sub-directory is used.

---

Per a comment suggestion, I tried turning my .htaccess into:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

[image: Browser Output]
[image: Console Output]

---

[image: Files]

Comment: Try removing 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: same results I'm afraid. I added screenshots of the results to the question

Comment: Removing those is not a good idea; you usually _want_ existing static assets delivered by the web server itself, and not via your PHP script.

Comment: So your .htaccess is in `public`, and you are rewriting to just `index.php` - but that folder does not appear to even contain one, according to your screenshot? What is your document root set to?

Comment: Using paths like `./assets/...` for your assets is not a good idea - that is relative to the current "folder" of the main document's URL. You should use paths that start with a slash, those are always relative to the domain root.

Comment: @CBroe - root is public, so htaccess and index are both there; however, doing `/assets` seems to have worked. Thank you.